# Is stat growth for mirages with transfigurations path independent?

Tags: world-of-final-fantasy

Does it matter which transfiguration a mirage is in when it levels up?

If I have two mirages of the same type (i.e. they can tranfigure to each other), and I level them up to the same level while taking different paths (i.e. different amount of levels spent in different transfigured forms, while activating the same nodes on their mirage board), and then I transfigure them both into the same mirage transfig form at the same level, will their stats be the same?

Are stats of a mirage path independent?